# How to log in Instagram via cUrl?

Tags: php, curl

```
$username = "login";
$password = "pass";
$cookie = $username.".txt";
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/50.0.2661.102 Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36";
$url = 'https://instagram.com/';
$arrSetHeaders = array(
    "User-Agent: $useragent",
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: deflate, br',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'cache-control: max-age=0'
    );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);

$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $page;
sleep(5);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $page, $matches);
$cookieFileContent = '';
foreach($matches[1] as $item) 
{
    $cookieFileContent .= "$item; ";
}

$cookieFileContent = rtrim($cookieFileContent, '; ');
$cookieFileContent = str_replace('sessionid=; ', '', $cookieFileContent);

$oldContent = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
$oldContArr = explode("\n", $oldContent);

if(count($oldContArr)) {
    foreach($oldContArr as $k => $line){
        if(strstr($line, '# ')){
            unset($oldContArr[$k]);
        }
    }
    $newContent = implode("\n", $oldContArr);
    $newContent = trim($newContent, "\n");
    file_put_contents( dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie, $newContent);
}

preg_match('|csrftoken(.*)|', file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie), $csrf);
$crf = trim($csrf[1]);
$arrSetHeaders = array(
    "User-Agent: $useragent",
    "X-CSRFToken: $crf",
    "x-csrftoken: $crf",
    'X-Instagram-AJAX: 1',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
    "Referer: https://instagram.com",
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: deflate, br',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'cache-control: max-age=0',
    );
$post = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' => $crf);
$url = 'https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/".$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://instagram.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($page);
```

returns bool(false)

what is wrong? how to log in instagram using curl request to accounts/login/ajax/

Comment: Do a `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` instead and show us what it said.

Comment: nothing more than var_dump(curl_error($ch)); => bool(false)

Comment: That is highly unlikely. From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error): _Returns the error message or '' (the empty string) if no error occurred_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:
I'm able to do a request in this way, i'm using curl.
I don't use any sort of cookie. Just the straight request

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  
-H "Accept: */*"
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
-H "Host: www.instagram.com" 
-H "Origin: https://www.instagram.com" 
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15" 
-H "Referer: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/" 
-H "Connection: keep-alive" 
-H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 
-H "X-IG-WWW-Claim: 0" 
-H "X-CSRFToken: $token" 
--data "username=$us&enc_password=%23PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER%3A0%3A$rand%3A$line&queryParams=%7B%7D&optIntoOneTap=false" --compressed "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/"
                 ^^^                                             ^^^^^   ^^^^^
```

```
$token is a 32 LENGTH ALPHANUMERIC STRING
Example: ZHMFltOnFJZMPdXyFdCCTsJrzEfSmGCg
$us is the username in PLAIN ASCII TEXT
Example: myaccount
$rand is a 10 LENGTH DIGIT STRING
Example: 9719014829
$line is the password in PLAIN ASCII TEXT
Example: mypassword
```

There are 3 possibile responses if the username is correct

```
authenticated:true -> Password was ok
authenticated:false -> Password not ok
checkpoint_required -> Password ok but request was blocked, the user has 2FA or 
the ip is blacklisted
```

:)

Comment: Solution found!

Comment: Does this still work?